# Three background images with CSS2 - not showing below the fold when you scroll

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I'm trying to get the background on my site to have three different background images - so I'm putting one image in the  and then using two absolutely positioned DIVs to add the other layers:

```
z-index: 2;
background: url(/assets/img/bg-stripes.png);
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

I'm finding that this works fine, but when you scroll, the divs are moving too - and it leads to a white gap showing at the bottom of the page - I can't unfortunately upload an image to demonstrate this, but you can preview the site here if you want to see exactly how I've done the CSS:
[Website Preview](http://rsctwentyeleven.ds6003.dedicated.turbodns.co.uk/)

I hope that makes sense - many thanks in advance for your help :)

Darren

Comment: DOH!  Yes, I think that's it JCO!! I will give it a quick cross-browser test now - I've obviously been looking at it for too long

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and post it as an answer, use `position:fixed;` to position elements so that they stay still when you scroll.